# I am facing this error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend\Uri\Uri' not found"

Tags: php, zend-framework2, fatal-error, zend-framework3

I am sharing some lines of code here which I am doing. my other validators are working currently but URI validator gives this error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend\Uri\Uri' not found" when i going to this path "http://localhost/applications/add". I have already added Zend URI validator in "vendor\zendframework\zend-validator\src\Uri.php"(for this I am sharing screen shot also).

```
<?php
use Zend\Filter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Input;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Validator;

class ApplicationsController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function addAction() {

        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

        $inputFilter->add(
            [
                'name' => 'web_uri',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => [
                    ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
                    ['name' => 'HtmlEntities']
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'NotEmpty'
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'Uri'
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
)
}
?>
```

This is code of "zendframework\zend-validator\src\Uri.php"

```
<?php
namespace Zend\Validator;

use Traversable;
use Zend\Uri\Exception\ExceptionInterface as UriException;
use Zend\Uri\Uri as UriHandler;
use Zend\Validator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;

class Uri extends AbstractValidator
{
}
?>
```

[image: this is my folders structure where Uri.php is exist]

[image: screen shot of error which I am getting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `Zend/Uri/Uri` is part of another package, `zendframework/zend-uri`, which is suggested by the validator. Take a look on [line 44 of zend-uri composer.json](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/composer.json#L44):

```
...
    "suggest": {
...
        "zendframework/zend-uri": "Zend\\Uri component, required by the Uri and Sitemap\\Loc validators"
    },
...
```

To solve this problem, execute this command from the project's root folder:

```sh
composer require zendframework/zend-uri
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Ermenegildo. It's working. 
Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello @Ermenegildo can you do one more help? I did add URI validation but it's not working its accepting everything. so can you tell me how we can add URI validation in the right manner?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Zend\Uri\Uri` use `Laminas\Uri\Uri`

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed the zend-uri package in your project.
So you have follow the [link](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-uri) to installation process.

OR

Run the following command in your project root directory.

```
$ composer require zendframework/zend-uri
```